# Git Fundamentals - Merging back into master

Tags: git

I'm new to git.

I made a branch, did my changes, and now I want to merge back to master to make them "permanent".

So I did `git merge 1.2` which reported as already up-to-date, did the same on master to the same result, and tried `merge -v HEAD master` which gave me a slightly different up-to-date message.

So is what I did correct? Should I be doing something else? How do I switch back to the master branch?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to be on the master branch to merge into it.

```
git checkout master
git merge some_development_effort
```

Comment: So 4 years later, I realized I never upvoted your answer, only accepted it. My belated appologies!

Answer (score 9):

You have your Master branch and then you have the branch which you are making changes on.  In order to merge the branch with changes back into Master you need to be on Master.

So first checkout Master and then run your merge:

```
git checkout master    
git merge 1.2
```